# Creating a pure CSS3 material toggle switch

Tags: android, css, cordova, webview, toggle

I am in the process of trying to create a lightweight toggle switch for use in a hybrid Android app - in place of my current effort which relies on scripting to deliver its magic.  Here is what I have accomplished thus far

```
.onoffBox
{
 text-align:left !important;
 padding:0.5em;
}

.onOffBox > span
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:90vw;
 text-align:left !important;
 color:white;
}

.inpOnOff
{
 display:none;
}

.inpOnOff + label
{
 width:10vw;
 float:right;
 background-color:silver;
 border-radius:3vw;
 height:3vw;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 position:relative;
}

.inpOnOff + label:before
{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 background-color:white;
 content:'';
 border-radius:5vw;
 height:5vw;
 width:5vw;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:-1vw;
}

.inpOnOff:checked + label{background-color:aqua;}
.inpOnOff:checked + label:before
{
 left:calc(100% - 5vw);
 background-color:aqua;
}
body{background-color:black;}

<div class='onOffBox'>
<span>Hide Hints</span>
 <input id='inpHideHints' class='inpOnOff' type='checkbox'/>
 <label for='inpHideHints' id='lblHideHints'></label>
</div>
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrpu5rs/1/) to see this in action.

Whilst this works I have two concerns

- I have never been too comfortable with `CSS float` so I am not sure that my usage here is correct
- You will notice that in the `input:checked` state I am using `CSS calc` to position the left hand side of the `label:before` pseudo-element.  Given that all of this is for an Android hybrid webapp I have a concern that earlier versions of the Android WebView may not understand `calc`.

I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest a few improvements or alternatives here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since managed to work out a better solution which I share here for the benefit of the community.

**The Objective**

- Create a material design lookalike toggle/on-off switch
- use only CSS3
- as lightweight as possible
- make the switch responsive to taps/clicks anywhere within its body

**The tricks used**

- Use a hidden HTML `checkbox` input element
- Style its successor `label` sibling to be a `relative`ly positioned `block` element
- Use the `label:before` pseudo element, absolutely positioned, to create the *track* for the on-off control
- Use the `label:after` pseudo element to create the slider for the control
- Use the `input:checked` pseudo element to make the control responsive

The code

```css
body{background-color:black;font-family:arial}
.inpOnOff{display:none;}
.inpOnOff + label
{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 margin:1vw;
 margin-bottom:1em;
 color:white !important;
}
.inpOnOff + label:before
{
 content:''; 
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 width:10vw;
 height:5vw;
 border-radius:5vw;
 background-color:silver;
}
.inpOnOff + label:after
{
 content:''; 
 position:absolute;
 right:5vw;
 height:5vw;
 width:5vw;
 border-radius:5vw;
 background-color:white;
 z-index:100;
}
.inpOnOff:checked + label:before{background-color:white;}
.inpOnOff:checked + label:after
{
 right:0;
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input class='inpOnOff' id='inpHideHint' type='checkbox'/>
<label for='inpHideHint'>Hide Hint</label>
```

The fact that the toggle control is embedded within the label itself ensures that the control is responsive to taps/clicks anywherre within its body.  A fringe benefit - more lightweight markup.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the float position for an absolute one, adjusting it to right: 0px (or whatever you like) and also set a margin. (this point is up to you).

About the calc for the left, it is also posible to avoid it positioning it with right: 0px (and overriding left from the other state)

```css
.onoffBox
{
 text-align:left !important;
 padding:0.5em;
}

.onOffBox > label
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:90vw;
 text-align:left !important;
 color:white;
}

.inpOnOff
{
 display:none;
}

.inpOnOff + span
{
 width:10vw;
 background-color:silver;
 border-radius:3vw;
 height:3vw;
 padding:0;
 margin: 10px;
 position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.inpOnOff + span:before
{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 background-color:white;
 content:'';
 border-radius:5vw;
 height:5vw;
 width:5vw;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:-1vw;
}

.inpOnOff:checked + span{background-color:aqua;}
.inpOnOff:checked + span:before
{
 left: initial;
  right: 0px;
 background-color:aqua;
}
body{background-color:black;}
```

```html
<div class='onOffBox'>
<label for='inpHideHints'>Hide Hints</label>
<input id='inpHideHints' class='inpOnOff' type='checkbox'/>
<span id='lblHideHints'></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Would there be a way to use `pointer-events` magic in some way to make the whole thing responsive to taps/clicks anywhere, i.e. even on the text on the l.h.s - Hide Hints in this example?

Comment: This is a standard behaviour for a label ...  I have changed what was a label to a span and viceversa, and now it works as you want